# Help understanding "If $ab>0$, then both $a$ and $b$ are positive or both are negative."

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Theorem I.24 from Apostol's Calculus states:

> If $ab>0$, then both $a$ and $b$ are positive or both are negative.

I am having a lot of trouble trying to prove it. This is my first encounter with axiomatic approach and field and order axioms, so I would prefer as simple a solution as possible so as to understand.

I am trying to prove it directly, by assuming $ab>0$ first. Then, I claim that it is not the case that $a=0$ or $b=0$, because then $ab=0$ which contradicts our assumption. So, $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$. Now, I plan on first assuming $a>0$ in addition to $ab>0$, and concluding $b>0$, though I am unsure how to arrive to that conclusion. Additionally, I will assume $a<0$ in addition to $ab>0$ and conclude that $b<0$.

Is this a valid approach? If so, can anybody help me flesh out these sub-cases? How do I arrive at my desired conclusions from the two sets of assumptions?

Here's an image of the problem and its page in the textbook, for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say “Now, I plan on first assuming $a>0$ in addition to $ab >0$, and concluding $b>0$”. So you want to show that if $a\in R^+$ and $ab \in R^+$ then $b \in R^+$. You can argue by contradiction: suppose $b \notin R^+$ then $-b \in R^+$ by Axiom 8. Then $a(-b)=-ab \in R^+$ by Axiom 7. So $ab \notin R^+$ by Axiom 8, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Just for clarification: Are we allowed to assume b is not in r+ during our proof by contradiciton because we have assumed b is not 0 and thus, by axiom8, -b must be in r+? It seems like the proof for the other case is roughly similar too so that's good. Does my proof in general make sense to you?

I was wondering if you had any other approaches to the problem that you see fit. I'd like to see as many approaches as possible. Thank you!

Comment: In a proof by contradiction you start by assuming the negation of what you are trying to prove, and then you derive a contradiction. . Here you are trying to prove $b \in R^+$ so you start by assuming the opposite. You then derive a contradiction as explained in my answer. To finish the proof you can indeed, as you say, show that if $a<0$ and $ab>0$ then $b<0$. A similar proof  by contradiction works.

Comment: I understand the general mechanics of a proof by contradiction, but just to be pedantic, when assuming the falsity of "b is in r+", that could really mean -b is in r+ or b = 0 right? But it is because b is not equal to zero and by axiom 8 that we can conclude that the contradiction means -b is in r+, right? Just want to make sure my logic has no holes.

Comment: Yes, you already dealt with the possibility that $b=0$ in your opening remarks so, as you say, we can assume $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$.